# installing java without the web aspect?

Tags: java, windows

i'd like to have the JDK/SDK on my machine, but don't want that coffee symbol to pop up when I got to some sites. I don't want web browsers to start running java.  I don't want it in my taskbar. I don't want it in the background.

I just want it for running some programs.  javac a.java (enter) java a. That's it.

Is that possible? if so, how?

Comment: you may not like this comment but this is the kind of stuff that is trivial on OS where you don't need to be admin/root to install anything (Java on Linux does not mandate root, but it does on Windows).  On Linux, for example, it is trivial to install one (or several) JRE in, say, one user account and none in another user account.  It is then trivial to display in one user's session programs running from another user.  For example I've got a *"/home/tmp/"* user account that has Chrome but no Java.  Yet I'm a Java developer: I just don't give a flying **** about applets/JWS.

Comment: I realize in your case it's doable to on Windows: but my point is that using an OS that allows you to use simultaneously several user accounts that are actually isolated gives you much, much more power than OSes that don't.

Comment: @Gugussee  running cmd.exe as whatever user doesn't give me power? use of several isolated accounts simultaneously?

Answer (score 4):

you just install it in standard way then you can configure all these from [java control panel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html)

Answer (score 2):

Install the JDK (Java Development Kit), and refuse the option of installing the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) when asked by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on that icon once, and tell it to shut down automatic update checking permanently.